# Google Places API: Change Powered Google logo color?

Tags: google-places-api

This looks like obvious but I cant find a way to change the color of the logo inside the autocomplete result box. Google provides dark version of their logo [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies) but trying to change it using CSS:

```
.pac-container:after {
  background-image: url('/images/google/powered_by_google_on_non_white_hdpi.png') !important;
}
```

Didn't work. I cant seem to find any API calls that would make the widget to fetch the other picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

actually this CSS did work in the end. It was a syntax error that made it not to work at the beggining.